# Jquery validation question, how to validate the empty field?

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using Jquery validation plugin for my form validation.

I just use  this one as sample.
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

there's one problem.  first time you load the form. click on the first field, dont put anything there, then click on the "tab" button to move to the next input field, the error message is not showing, but that field is labeled as "required".

is there a way to fix it? or that is how it supposed to be it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make the validation error messages appear as the input boxes lose focus rather than the form submit??

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Validate plugin's reference for `onblur`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

> If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as invalid.

But you can force it to validate yourself by binding the inputs' `blur` event:

```
$("#signupform input").blur(function() {
    $(this.form).validate().element(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id).filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; });
```

You can get fields with empty value and ca validate.

You can also add class and can get all empty fields of that class i.e.

```
$('.className).filter(function() { 
    return $(this).val() == ""; 
});
```